# Modify Default Visual C++ Item Templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio Community 2013 it's not possible to create and use your own item templates in a C++ project.

I need to be able to add new extensionless source code files to my projects. Now, everytime I add a new source file I need to rename the file afterwards in the Solution Explorer and remove the `.cpp` extension because it's just added automatically when the item is created.
Is there a file somewhere that has something like: `TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cpp"` where I can just remove the `.cpp` part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is to make an "Add New Item Wizard".

I'm trying to make one, but I can only find documentation on how to make a "New Project Wizard" instead.

I posted a new question: [Create “Add New Item Wizard” in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200350/create-add-new-item-wizard-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems

Modify the second to last line the c source file line with any changes you need. including removing the .cpp.