# Create "Add New Item Wizard" in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Maybe I'm not searching with the right keywords, but I'm unable to find documentation on how to make your own "Add New Item Wizard" in Visual Studio Community 2013 for C++ projects.

What I want to achieve is to be able to add new extensionless source files to my C++ projects from `Project > Add New Item...` instead of adding a C++ Source File and deleting the `.cpp` extension in the Solution Explorer afterwards.

First I tried to make my own template, but it turns out, that that is not possible with C++ Projects in Visual Studio.
Second I tried to see if I can modify one of the default templates ([Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176432/modify-default-visual-c-item-templates/)), but that is also not possible.

I'm reading this documentation: [MSDN: Walkthrough: Creating a Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59.aspx), but I can only find instructions on how to make a "New Project Wizard" and not an "Add New Item Wizard".

What I am missing here?

Comment: This might help: [Adding Items to the Add New Item Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165141.aspx)

Comment: It is possible to create C++ templates.. From VS 2012 upwards, C++ is supported. This must be the easiest way.

Comment: @Nikolay Hi. Only project templates, I'm afraid. In the MSDN documentation about the subject is a small note that states that: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried it? File -> Export Template in C++ project.

Comment: Yep, seems to be broken in VS 2013. Seems to work in VS 2012 and in 2013 Express. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858102/visual-studio-2013-c-item-templates-missing

Comment: @Nikolay You can export, but it does nothing when you add it to your `ItemTemplates` folder (in C# and VB works fine). Now I just added my custom file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems` and I think it works! --Thank you for making me try that one more time! I will play around with it a little more and see if this is the solution. I hope the next version of VS has the "Export Item Template" functionality in C++ as well.

Comment: Cool :) Maybe somebody should create an issue in Microsoft connect. Seems to be odd that it works in Express, but does not in Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the solution for what I specifically wanted to do was quite simple after all:

Instead of exporting and adding an "Item Template" (a feature that in the last version of VS does not work for C++ projects) or modifying the default item templates, or trying to make my own Wizard; You can just go to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems` and copy your custom template files there. You should also modify the `.vsdir` files in that directory by hand for further customization. I used [this reference](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29839&seqNum=6) to specify an icon and change the sorting order.

It's not so nice like in the C# or VB parts of Visual Studio where you can just use the Export Wizard to add new project and item templates to the corresponding dialogs and have them stored in your templates folder. I will write some feedback to the VS team and hope they fix this in the next version.