# Visual Studio 2019 - Set a default extension for a file type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio uses `.cpp` for cpp source files and `.h` for cpp header files by default. I want to change the extensions to `.cc` and `.hh`, respectively. Is there a way to configure Visual Studio?

PS: I know this is not very important but, I just like it that way.

Comment: You mean, when you create a new source file within a project, you want the extension to be `.cc` by default. I'm not sure this is possible. If you mean, that you want to associate `.cc` files with visual studio, you can do this in Windows settings (default programs).

Comment: Visual Studio recognizes `.cc` files as C++ but, I have to manually rename all the files. I want to know if there is some way to configure `VS 2019`  to use `.cc` and `.hh` by default.

Comment: Related: [Create “Add New Item Wizard” in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200350/create-add-new-item-wizard-in-visual-c).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your question's solution is, quite frankly, of dubious practical value. While you might satisfy you're "I just like it that way" preference, you're trying to change convention--expected, standardized extensions for one of the world's most popular programming languages and sealing yourself off from many third-party tools and technologies by doing so. You'll have difficulty sharing your code or integrating it; even if you write T4 templates, batch files, project item templates, etc., to support your preference, it's at a very high cost.

The short answer is that there is no quick-fix for doing what you're asking. The long story is that you could toil away and make progress towards your goal, but you'll experience a major setback with every file extension you're trying to change.

My advice: Stick with the expected file extensions and devote your efforts to mastering C# instead.